Transform one column into multiple ones based on two other columns
I have the following data in Clickhouse



date
value
type
subtype




2021-01-01
1
A
x


2021-01-01
2
A
y


2021-01-01
3
B
x


2021-01-01
4
B
y


2021-01-02
5
A
x


2021-01-02
6
A
y


2021-01-02
7
B
x


2021-01-02
8
B
y



I need to transform it into the following form



date
Ax
Ay
Bx
By




2021-01-01
1
2
3
4


2021-01-02
5
6
7
8



The combinations of Type and Subtype are known.
I tried the following query
SELECT
    date,
    case when type = 'A' and subtype = 'x' then value end Ax,
    case when type = 'A' and subtype = 'y' then value end Ay,
    case when type = 'B' and subtype = 'x' then value end Bx,
    case when type = 'B' and subtype = 'y' then value end By
FROM my_table

but it returns



date
Ax
Ay
Bx
By




2021-01-01
1
null
null
v


2021-01-02
null
2
null
v


2021-01-01
null
null
3
null


2021-01-02
null
null
null
4


2021-01-01
5
null
null
null


2021-01-02
null
6
null
null


2021-01-01
null
null
7
null


2021-01-02
null
null
null
8



What should I do to create the data I need without nulls

You're close. Just add a group by date. That would mean you wrap all case expressions inside min/max/any_value.

Group by date and use any with a filter clause to select the right value:
select
    date,
    any(value) filter (where type = 'A' and subtype = 'x') Ax,
    any(value) filter (where type = 'A' and subtype = 'y') Ay,
    any(value) filter (where type = 'B' and subtype = 'x') Bx,
    any(value) filter (where type = 'B' and subtype = 'y') By
from my_table
group by date

any will select the first value that matches the filter.
Output:
"date","Ax","Ay","Bx","By"
"2021-01-01",1,2,3,4
"2021-01-02",5,6,7,8

Full code:
create table my_table (
    date Date,
    value Int32,
    type String,
    subtype String
)
engine = MergeTree()
order by ();

insert into my_table (date, value, type, subtype)
values
    ('2021-01-01', 1, 'A', 'x'),
    ('2021-01-01', 2, 'A', 'y'),
    ('2021-01-01', 3, 'B', 'x'),
    ('2021-01-01', 4, 'B', 'y'),
    ('2021-01-02', 5, 'A', 'x'),
    ('2021-01-02', 6, 'A', 'y'),
    ('2021-01-02', 7, 'B', 'x'),
    ('2021-01-02', 8, 'B', 'y');

select
    date,
    any(value) filter (where type = 'A' and subtype = 'x') Ax,
    any(value) filter (where type = 'A' and subtype = 'y') Ay,
    any(value) filter (where type = 'B' and subtype = 'x') Bx,
    any(value) filter (where type = 'B' and subtype = 'y') By
from my_table
group by date
format CSVWithNames;


You are looking for a standard pivot query.  In this case, you should be aggregating by date using GROUP BY, and then taking the MAX() of the various CASE expressions:
SELECT
    date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'A' AND subtype = 'x' THEN value END) Ax,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'A' AND subtype = 'y' THEN value END) Ay,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'B' AND subtype = 'x' THEN value END) Bx,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'B' AND subtype = 'y' THEN value END) By
FROM my_table
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;


Using pivot after concat.
with cte as ( select
                    date,value,concat(type,subtype) cn
                    from my_table)
                    select * from cte
                    pivot ( max(value) for cn in ( any order by cn ) );

